# How can i find minimum count in a given date range

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to allocate workers for a job for a specific date range and wanted to find out the minimum number of workers allocated for the given date range.

For example, my table contains

```
startDate     endDate       No.of.Workers
---------    ---------     ---------------
1-1-2019     10-1-2019           1
11-1-2019    20-1-2019           1
```

now, i wanted to find out the minimum no of workers working in date range 1-1-2019 to 20-1-2019.
The output should be 1.

Suppose my table looks like,

```
startDate      endDate      No.of.Workers
---------     ---------    ---------------
1-1-2019      10-1-2019           1
11-1-2019     20-1-2019           1
11-1-2019     15-1-2019           1
```

The output should be 2.

Is there any query for this in sql or i need to write an algorithm?

I am using mysql database.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of workers needed by splitting the data, aggregating and using cumulative sums:

```
with dtes as (
      select startDate as dte, numworks
      from t
      union all
      select endDate as dte, - numworks
      from t
     )
select dte, sum(numworks),
       sum(sum(numworks)) over (order by dte) as needed
from dtes
group by dte
order by dte;
```

To get the maximum, you can do something like this:

```
select dte, sum(numworks),
       sum(sum(numworks)) over (order by dte) as needed
from dtes
group by dte
order by needed desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

You don't specify the database, `fetch first` is ISO/ANSI standard SQL.

Also, it is not clear if the end date counts as one of the days.  This can affect the results.  If it is included, then you need to add one day to the "endDate" part of the logic.  How you do that depends on your database.

Comment: i use mysql database

Comment: This works in MySQL 8, except that the `fetch first 1 row only` should be `limit 1`

Comment: can you please explain the solution